# Is there anything wrong with this piece of LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

For those of you who are familiar with my questions, you would know that I'm a newbie.

If you aren't, well you know now.

What is wrong with the following piece of LaTeX? MathJax won't render it as correct.

```
\frac{2^5}{2^{-2}}\\=2^5^{-\left(-2\right)}\\=2^{5+2}\\=2^7\\=128
```

This is in MathJax, so there wouldn't be anything fancy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure about MathJax, but as far as LaTeX is concerned the only problem is the double superscript. Try changing the second line to

```
2^{5-(-2)}
```

(or including the `\left` and `\right` if you want, although they won't affect anything in this particular case because what is inside them, -2, fits on a single line).